# Check if mysql row exisits within foreach loop of php array

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have an array of items that I am looping over and checking if the value already exists in the database, if it does I would like to update it, if it does not I would like to create a new entry.  The first item in the array is seen and returns true, but anything after the first one returns 0 even if I know for a fact that it is in the database with the correct item_name and ticket_id.

I have tried researching before asking, but am stumped at this point.  Thanks for any help in advance.

```
if($func == 'edit') {

        foreach ($addItem as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($key) || $key=='amount_paid') {
    continue;
  }
            $ticket_items = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ticket_items WHERE ticket_id = '$ticket_id' AND item_name = '$key'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($ticket_items)) {
                print 'Updated '. $key ."\n";
                mysql_query("UPDATE ticket_items set item_name='$key', item_price='$value' WHERE ticket_id='$ticket_id'");
            } else {
                print 'Created '. $key ."\n";
            mysql_query("INSERT into ticket_items (ticket_id, item_name, item_price) VALUES ('$ticket_id', '$key', '$value')");     
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The $ticket_id is the same in every iteration of your loop. Is that intended?

Comment: yes all items in the array have the same ticket_id

Comment: maybe it is skipping you should add echo in `(empty($key) || $key=='amount_paid') ` condition also count the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, in your UPDATE statement, you are updating every row that has the same $ticket_id, regardless of the item_name. It should be:

```
UPDATE ticket_items set item_name='$key', item_price='$value' WHERE ticket_id='$ticket_id' AND item_name='$key';
```

Comment: So simple, I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like at the first update, you are resetting the data for all Tickets in the db.

> mysql_query("UPDATE ticket_items set item_name='$key', item_price='$value' WHERE ticket_id='$ticket_id'");

Above one sets the key and value to the same value for all the rows of that ticket.

you should try smt like below:

> mysql_query("UPDATE ticket_items set item_price='$value' WHERE ticket_id='$ticket_id' and item_name='$key'") ;